# PHP ob_end_flush() doesn't close browser connection

Tags: php, background-process

We have been relying on this for some time and recently changed servers. Basically at the end of a php file we close the connection and do some heavy lifting we don't want the browser to hang up on. In my experience this method we use closes the browsers connection and the user doesn't experience anything. On this new server the connection is staying open and causing the browser to hang.

I made this really simple test file to play with it:

```
<?php
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
testing...
</body>
</html>

<?
$size = ob_get_length();
header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Connection: close');
ob_end_flush();

//anything below this should NOT hang up the browser
sleep(30); //but it does :-(
?>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. Please post `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PHP. Your new server probably supports Keep Alive connections (which your browser most certainly solicits) causing the connection to remain open for subsequent requests. Try adding Header("Connection: close") to your script or turn off Keep Alive support in your web server.

Comment: header("Connection: close") is in the original code above. I will contact the server owner and look into "Keep Alive." I will return when I find an answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: My host claims they don't have "Keep Alive" turned on.